# Value is undefined when accessing dynamically in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am using Jquery to access the window object in the document.
I can able to get the value when I try to access directly like

```
 $([window.configData.Json_tag][0].PAGENAME);
```

But when I passing it from a text box value, i am getting it as undefined.

```
 var key = $('#jsonKey').val();//key contains the value window.configData.Json_tag
 console.log(key);
 console.log($([key])[0].PAGENAME);//Getting Undefied
```

**PAGENAME** is a key in the **window.configData.Json_tag**

window.configData.Json_tag = {"PAGENAME":"Test","Context":"Document"};

Could somebody help me in getting the value dynamically.

Comment: `var key = $('#jsonKey').val();` is a String value, not an array, or an object. It doesn't have `[0]` element, and `.PAGENAME` property too, check this http://api.jquery.com/val/ .

Comment: @AndrewEvt But the value of the key I am passing is an object in the document. I am passing it dynamically to jquey.

Comment: you are passing the object, but it doesn't return it, it returns JSON string maybe.. Try `var realKey = JSON.parse(key);` and work with it next. JSON String is a string, not an real object

Answer (score 2):

```
$([key])[0].PAGENAME
```

should be

```
$(JSON.parse(key).PAGENAME);
```

Check the `parenthesis`.

Comment: I am getting an empty array in this case.. []

Comment: Check the updated answer. Use `$(JSON.parse(key).PAGENAME);`

Comment: key = window.configData.ensighten_tag. 
It is the text box value that is coming dynamically

Comment: I didn't asked that. Show me what `var key` stores? If it is a json, show me that?

Comment: yes, with `JSON.parse` it should work. Read more about JSON and how to work with it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON